# can't update a foreign key but i can delete it already set on CASCADE for both

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, referential-integrity

I tried every solution I can find for this and non of them worked.

To explain: I'm trying to update a primary key `code_class` in the table `classroom`. This key is also a foreign key in the `reservation` table.

I keep gettimg this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
> foreign key constraint fails (`ebooking`.`reservation`, CONSTRAINT
> `reservation_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`code_class`) REFERENCES `classroom`
> (`code_class`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in
> C:\wamp64\www\last\ebooking2\profile\admin\updateClass.php on line
> 38

But I can delete the same key. I would like to mention that they are both set on `CASCADE`, as the error says.

here is my Update php code

```
$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM classroom Where code_class = :C ');
$requete->execute(array('C'=> $CR));
          while ($donnees = $requete->fetch()){
            if (isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)) {
                $data = [
                    'name' => $_POST['Code'],
                    'surname' => $_POST['STIME'],
                    'floor' => $_POST['fTIME'],
                    'roomtp' => $_POST['ETIME'],
                    'hard'=> $_POST['HARD'],
                    'id' => $CR,
                ];
                $sql = "UPDATE classroom SET code_class=:name,capacity=:surname,floor=:floor,room_type=:roomtp,
                hardware_type=:hard WHERE code_class=:id ";
                $stmt= $bdd->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute($data);
                // echo "<script>window.location.assign('hardware.php')</script>";
            }
```

and my delete code

```
<?php
// error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include('../../connexionDB.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['CR']) ||$_SESSION['CR'] == ""){
   echo 'no id found';
}else {
    $AS = $_SESSION['CR'];
  
}
echo $AS;
$sql = "DELETE FROM `classroom` WHERE code_class =:c ";
    $statement = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam('c', $AS);

// execute the statement
if ($statement->execute()) {
    echo 'publisher id  was deleted successfully.';
 
      }
?>
```

the key

```
ALTER TABLE `reservation` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`code_class`) REFERENCES `classroom`(`code_class`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I can't see the problem - can someone help?

Comment: No. It's hard to see anything here other than the error message which is clear enough

Comment: i tried to put the code but stack edited the question

Comment: actually it was YOU  who for some reason removed the code

Comment: it's back on ..... AND i did what stack asked me too i posted this question yesterday but it got blocked for some reason i had to edite it